# Laravel(Shared hosting) - File not defined in asset manifest

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to running a laravel project in a shared hosting but i'm having the error: `File css/app-backend.css not defined in asset manifest` .

My folder structure is that:

```
- .htaccess
- css
- js
- laravel-code
- index.php
```

I edit the `index.php` :

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel-code/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel-code/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I also change the src of css and js files. Instead elixir i change to asset.

How can i solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing or have an outdated manifest file from the /public folder.

When you use the asset() function it looks to a /public/manifest.json file to determine which files it loads ( for things like using versioning with elixir you can just reference 'js/app.js' and it'd really point to 'js/app.1980L1209.js )

I can't pinpoint it exactly but I'd look to your manifest file for some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have not updated the server.php file. Try updating line 21 to this

```
require_once __DIR__.'/laravel-code/public/index.php';
```